# Finding the rate at which the space diagonal of a cube is decreasing

Tags: derivatives, problem-solving, chain-rule

This is the context of the question: [image]

I'm assuming by the space diagonal (although I'm not sure) to be the area of the right-angled traingle created by the diagonal. Let this space be $V$, then we will have $V=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}x^2$, where $x$ is the lenght of the edges at time $t$. Now, $\frac{dV}{dx}=\sqrt{2}x$, and $\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dV}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=2\sqrt{2}x$. But, we haven't directly been told $x$ abd I can't think of anyway to find it. Can anyone suggest what I do?

(The answer is supposed to be $-2\sqrt{3} cm/s$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. The space diagonal is the line connecting two vertices of the cube not belonging to the same face. So it is the hypothenuse of a rectangle triangle whose edges are $a$ and $a\sqrt{2}$ (diagonal of one of the faces), where $a$ is the edge length. This means that $sd=a\sqrt{3}$ and therefore the rate of decrease is $\dot{a}\sqrt{3}=-2\sqrt{3}$ as expected.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $ds$ and how did you arrive at $\sqrt{3}a=ds$?

Comment: It should be $sd$ for space diagonal and the Pythagoras theorem tells us that $sd^2=a^2+(a\sqrt{2})^2$

Comment: Hey @marwalix just curious. The angle between a space diagonal and any one of its edge is approx 55 degrees right? For a cube with unit length.

Comment: @Gaurang Chauhan Yes it is $\tan^{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and this is approximately $54°45'$

Comment: @marwalix, thanks for the response. Right  understandable.